# Apple Pay detect Wallet has no credit cards

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

I am trying to implement Apple Pay for my app. I have the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController trying to load up the Apple Pay View. This view controller was being returned as Nil by the constructor if I didn't have any cards already in my wallet. So, I decided to guide the user though the process where they enter their card information. I was able to achieve this using

```
PKPassLibrary* lib = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];
[lib openPaymentSetup];
```

Here is the part where I have the initialization of the PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController. This returns a valid object on Simulator showing the view. But on a real device without a configured credit card returns nil and runs into an runtime exception. Here is the initialization code:

```
if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments]) {
// init arr
[arr addObject:total];
request.paymentSummaryItems = arr;
PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *paymentPane = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
paymentPane.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:paymentPane animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

Here the array is a valid NSArray of PKPaymentSummaryItem which is why is successfully works on simulator.

I need to call the above method of openPaymentSetup, everytime I see a user without the credit card in their wallet. Is there a way to detect that?

Currently I am using

```
if ( [PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable] ) {
    PKPassLibrary* lib = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];
    if  ([lib passesOfType:PKPassTypePayment].count == 0 ) {
        [lib openPaymentSetup];
   }
}
```

But this will not work since I am looking at the count of passes in wallet. Which may be like boarding pass for airline, or eventbrite pass, etc.

Looked at :
[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController present as nil view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992970/pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller-present-as-nil-view-controller)

[Apple pay PKPaymentauthorizationViewController always returning nil when loaded with Payment request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525861/apple-pay-pkpaymentauthorizationviewcontroller-always-returning-nil-when-loaded)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController_Ref/

Comment: is there a reason you can't use the canMakePayments method from the apple documentation? (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController/canMakePayments)

Comment: @bplattenburg It always returns true. Check the edit.

Comment: You need to use the `canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:` method, not the `canMakePayments` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did as suggested by @maddy, and it actually worked. Its unfortunate that apple has very limited documentation about it. Thanks Maddy.

Here is my code

```
-(BOOL) openAddCardForPaymentUIIfNeeded
{
    if ( [PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable] )
    {
        if ( ![PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa, nil]] )
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add a Credit Card to Wallet" message:@"Would you like to add a credit card to your wallet now?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
            [alert show];
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I am directing the user to go to add a card wizard in the wallet app. Is there any way I can get the user back to the App after he/she has finished adding the card in the Wallet?

Thanks!

Comment: No way to get them back without the user going back to your app as far as I know. I would hope people can figure that much out for themselves though :)